# UILabel doesn't change height on setFrame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to change the height of a `UILabel` depending on how much text is in the label.

I can calculate the size required for the label but when I try to set the `UILabel` frame it just doesn't change.

Below is my code. 
Even if I replace size.height in the last line to something like 500 the size of the `UILabel` frame doesn't change

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"GameItemCell";
    GameItemCell *cell = (GameItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameItemCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    GameItem* item = [_hunt.gameItems objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];


    cell.itemHeaderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%d - (%d pts)", indexPath.row+1, item.itemPoints];

    UILabel* textLabel = cell.itemTextLabel;

    textLabel.text = item.itemText;
    textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


    CGRect frame = cell.itemTextLabel.frame;
    CGSize textSize = { frame.size.width, 20000.0f };
    CGSize sizeOneLine = [@"one line" sizeWithFont:cell.itemTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGSize cellTextSize = [item.itemText sizeWithFont:cell.itemTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGSize sizeOneLineSpacing = CGSizeMake(sizeOneLine.width, sizeOneLine.height + 3);
    NSInteger lines = cellTextSize.height / sizeOneLine.height;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, lines * sizeOneLineSpacing.height);

    textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check if your textLabel variable is not nil when you try to set its frame?

Comment: Are you adding the label in tableview cell? and also check textLabel reference is nil(print textLabel using NSLog).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must set the frame of your label in GameItemCell inside `-(void)layoutSubviews`

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me mad and I thought the change had to made in GameItemCell somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing all that hard work, try it like:

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
textLabel.text = textString;
[textLabel sizeToFit];
```

remember `sizeToFit` respect your labels default width, so set width according to your requirement. And then Height will be managed by the `sizeToFit` method.

Comment: Thanks handy function to use but as LetaOn has said the change needed to be made in GameItemCell

Comment: You also need to make sure you increase the height of the labels frame.

Answer (score 2):

In the end you will need to put something like these two methods in your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
// call this method on your cell, during cellForRowAtIndexPath
// provide your resizing info (frame, height, whatever)

- (void) updateLabelFrame:(CGRect)newLabelFrame {
    self.resizedLabelFrame = newLabelFrame;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

// the actual resize happens here when UIKit gets around to it

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.myLabel.frame = self.resizedLabelFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `numberOfLines` property to set.

Add :

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: @AsifHabib I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

**numberOfLines**

The maximum number of lines to use for rendering text.

**The default value for this property is 1.** To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

tack a look [UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

According to your question you can set no of lines

Now number of lines is not set to your label,  so set it,

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect labelFrame = myLabel.frame;

labelFrame.size = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];

cell.textLabel.frame = labelFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, for multiple lines use textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; in cellForRowAtIndexPath

But Still you need to change the height of the cell too:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Calculate new cell height too as you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath 
    return YOUR_SIZE;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        NSString *text1 = shareObjC.commentText;
        CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(280 - (size.width + 5), 2000);

        CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        UILabel *lblComment = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posx,posy,size1.width,size1.height)] autorelease];

        lblComment.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lblComment.numberOfLines = size1.height/15;
        [lblComment setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        lblComment.text = text1;
        [cell.viewLikeComment addSubview:lblComment];
```