# UILabel setFrame is not resizing the label, even in layoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, frame

I've got:

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface CustomTableViewCell ()
@property (assign) CGRect titleFrame;
@property (assign) CGRect detailFrame;
@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if (self.title != nil) {
        self.titleFrame = self.title.frame;
    }
    if (self.detail != nil) {
        self.detailFrame = self.detail.frame;
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) setTitleTo: (NSString *)text {
    if (self.title == nil || text == nil) {
        return;
    }

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.title.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGRect expectedLabelSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                  options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.title.font}
                                                  context:nil];
    CGRect newFrame = self.title.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.size.height;
    self.titleFrame = newFrame;

    self.detail.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.detail.numberOfLines = 3;

    [self.title setText:text];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void) setDetailTo: (NSString *)text {
    if (self.detail == nil || text == nil) {
        return;
    }

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.detail.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGRect expectedLabelSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                  options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.title.font}
                                                  context:nil];
    CGRect newFrame = self.detail.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.size.height;
    self.detailFrame = newFrame;

    self.detail.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.detail.numberOfLines = 3;

    [self.detail setText:text];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}


- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.title != nil) {
        NSLog(@"T: %@", self.title.text);
        [self.title setFrame:self.titleFrame];
    }
    if (self.detail != nil) {
        NSLog(@"D: %@", self.detail.text);
        [self.detail setFrame:self.detailFrame];
    }
}
@end
```

From what I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130478/uilabel-doesnt-change-height-on-setframe) it should resize to fit the text.

[image: screen shot]

and the NSLog output:

```
2014-10-08 20:48:29.474 Test[57397:613] T: Largest Metro
2014-10-08 20:48:29.475 Test[57397:613] D: Oahu metropolitan area
```

My understanding is the "Oahu metropolitan area" should be visible with "area" on the second line.

Comment: Would you consider using auto layout instead of computing frame manually?

Comment: @KenKuan- I'm slowly converting it over as I type. Trying to learn exactly how constraints work on the way :)

Answer (score 1):

Three things you should change:

- Move the size computation of your label to `layoutSubviews`.
- The most precise way to compute a label's size is to use `-[UILabel sizeThatFits:]` to get the it's desired size.
- Turn off auto layout

Comment: Changing where and how the calculation is done will effect the actual changing of the size? Its like the `setFrame` isn't working.

Comment: @Justin808 That was my intention. The label would be resized exactly at the time it's layouted => much more accurate. And the label would be resized using a method which knows **exactly** how it will render. `boundingRectWithSize` for example doesn't know that your label is limited to 3 lines. --- Did you check that all frame properties are correct at the time you call `setFrame:`? --- Do you use auto layout in this view? Afaik auto layout ignores the frames you set manually.

Comment: Not sure whats going on. I moved over to your suggestions, the calculation is in `layoutSubviews` and I'm using `sizeThatFits:` to make the calculation. The label frame size changes - I can `NSLog` it, but on screen nothing happens. If I scroll off screen and back on, it displays correctly. Only the initial display is wrong.

Comment: @Justin808 Can you please update your code and log output? Also can you give the labels and the table view cell all different background colors? That way it's easier to spot some problems here.